# Generate graphs from the output of GraphAutomorphismGroup

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"] 
GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]
```

outputs

> `PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2, 5}, {3, 4}}]}]`

which I understand as changing `2 -> 5`, and `3 -> 4` will give an automorphic graph. This is true when tested:

```
g2 = Graph[{1 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
IsomorphicGraphQ[g, g2]
```

> `True`

With any given graph, I want to explicitly generate all the automorphic graphs (cause I want to compare adjacency matrices), can I use `PermutationGroup` and `Cycles` to do this or it's easier if I just dump these parts of the expression and use `Replace`?

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = With[{g = #,  vl = VertexList[#], 
         pvl = Permute[ VertexList[#], GraphAutomorphismGroup[#]]}, 
         SetProperty[VertexReplace[g,Thread[vl->#]], 
          {VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 300}]& /@ pvl]&;

g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Row[f @ g]
```

[image]

```
Row[f @ CycleGraph[5, VertexLabels->"Name", DirectedEdges->True]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
And @@ (IsomorphicGraphQ[g2, #] & /@ f[g2])
```

> True

```
g3= PetersenGraph[5,2];
And@@(IsomorphicGraphQ[g3,#]&/@f[g3])
```

> True

Comment: You just get five automorphic graphs, but it has ten.

Answer (score 2):

```
AutomorphicGraphs[g_] := VertexReplace[g, Thread[VertexList[g] -> #]] & /@ 
                              Permute[VertexList[g], GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]]
```

**For your graph:**

```
g1=Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->1,4->1,1->5,5->4},VertexLabels->"Name"];
AutomorphicGraphs[g1]
```

[image]

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[g1,#]&/@%
```

> {True,True}

**For the cycle graph:**

```
g2=CycleGraph[5,VertexLabels->"Name"];
AutomorphicGraphs[g2]
```

[image]

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[g2,#]&/@%
```

> {True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True}